# How to resolve the error "no file uploaded" in uploading a photo in javascript using the multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, multer

As I am going to click the post button in uploading a photo there is an error. And that error is in the image below. Can you help me fix these error. I already troubleshoot but my knowledge about these type of error is limited so maybe you can help me to be fix it. by the way i use xampp server for my database.

[image: As I am going to click the post button in uploading a photo there is an error. And that error is in the image below. Can you help me fix these error. I already troubleshoot but my knowledge about these type of error is limited so maybe you can help me to be fix it. by the way i use xampp server for my database.]

```
//get all gallery

const { queryDb } = require('@api/utils/mysql');

module.exports = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        var {

        } = req.body;

        message= '';

        var gallery = await queryDb('SELECT * FROM gallery');
        
        return res.status(200).json ({
            gallery
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        // console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: `Server error : ${err.message}`
        });
    }
}
```

**Uploading a photo**

```
tconst express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { DB_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, queryDb } = require('@api/utils/mysql');

//const app = express();
//const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000;
const router = express.Router();

// Set up storage for uploaded files
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    //cb(null, '../assets/uploads');
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '/assets/uploads'));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
    const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + fileExtension);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Serve uploaded files statically
//app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
router.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

// Handle file upload
router.post('/api/upload-photo', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  // You can perform additional logic here, like saving the file path to a database
  // and returning a response.

    try {
        //const { image = '' } = req.body;

        if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
        }
        // if (!image) {
        //  return res.status(400).json({
        //      message: 'No file uploaded.',
        //  });
        // }

        const imagePath = `/uploads/${req.file.filename}`; // Update the path to match your file storage location

        // Save file path to the database
        await queryDb(`
            INSERT INTO gallery (date_uploaded, image) VALUES (?, ?)`,
            [DB_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, imagePath]
        );

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Image Uploaded!'
        });
        
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: `Server error : ${err.message}`
        });
    }
  
//   res.status(200).json({ message: 'Image Uploaded' });
});

// app.listen(port, () => {
//   console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
// });
module.exports = router;
```

I already tried what fixing it, I followed what was in the internet said but it not work, so I hope you all can help me I really need to fix these error. and I already ask someone for help but they didn't know because they use different language.

Comment: Please add the HTML of the upload form.